# How to add custom method in product interface.And how to overide productinterface and product model

Tags: magento2, overrides, interface

I want to add custom method in product interface and override product interface and product model.

Comment: which method from product model you want to override?

Comment: I want to add my custom method in the product model.

Comment: And where you want to call it?

Comment: When product rest API call i want to add my custom image array in response.

Comment: I want to add my custom method in the product interface and product model.

Comment: Guide me how to override product interface and product model.